# What is the best way to step through an NPM Package

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, npm

I would like to add a feature to an open source NPM package.

I know what needs to happen, but it would be very useful to be able to step through the package while it is processing. Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are both command line and graphical debugging options that will let you step through your own code, npm module code, node core code (JS), etc. I use the [node-inspector](http://howtonode.org/debugging-with-node-inspector) module to hook chrome's web inspector graphical debugger up to a running node process. It works really well.